# How do I fix ExtJS layout errors? containerChildrenDone:dom not set

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm upgrading my code from ExtJS 4.0.7 to 4.1.1 and I'd struggling with some layout errors. I've fixed a few by adding in some missing height and width properties but the final one has me stumped.

I've attached some of output from the layout debug below. The portion beginning `--assetfield-1181` is the problem, but I've no idea what the error message means. I can't find any reference to a 'dom' property or containerChildDone in the docs.

```
++componenteditor-1180<anchor> - boxParent: attributeeditor-1017 - size: natural/shrinkWrap
  --assetfield-1181<autocontainer> - size: calculated/configured
        triggeredBy: count=1
           assetfield-1181.containerChildrenDone:dom () dirty: false, setBy: ?
     ++label-1193<autocomponent> - size: natural/shrinkWrap
     ++gridpanel-1182<dock> - size: natural/configured
        ++headercontainer-1183<autocomponent> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/configured
        ++headercontainer-1183<gridcolumn> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/configured
           ++gridcolumn-1184<columncomponent> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/calculatedFromShrinkWrap
           ++actioncolumn-1185<columncomponent> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/calculatedFromShrinkWrap
     ++gridpanel-1182<autocontainer> - size: natural/configured
        ++gridview-1186<tableview> - boxParent: gridpanel-1182 - size: natural/shrinkWrap
     ++button-1192<button> - size: shrinkWrap/shrinkWrap
  ++assetfield-1181<autocomponent> - size: calculated/configured
  ++checkboxfield-1194<field> - size: calculated/shrinkWrap
  ++checkboxfield-1195<field> - size: calculated/shrinkWrap
```